# error in compilation servlet program

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I am getting compilation error in servlet class while attempting to compile a program..

code:

```
import javax.servlet.*;   
import java.io.*;  
public class Servlet1 extends GenericServlet  
{   
     pubilc void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException  
 {  
  PrintWriter out= res.getWriter();   
  out.println("<html>");  
  out.println("<body bgcolor=pink>");  
  out.println("<h1> hello client <h1>");  
  out.println("</body>");  
  out.println("</html>");`  
 }  
}
```

error:

```
<identifier> excepted  
     public void service (ServletRequereq, ServletRespons res) throws ServletException,IOException
invalid method declaration; return type required 
    public void service(ServletRequereq, ServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
```

Answer (score 3):

Small typo: `pubilc` should be `public`